# Firebase admin sdk - http v1 API - How to ensure whether the Firebase API(sendEach) is using HTTP/2 or HTTP/1.1 as both are supported by Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

We are migrating the `sendAll` API to [`sendEach` API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messaging#messagingsendeach) as part of Firebase ADMIN SDK migration.

From documentation, it is mentioned as below

> The FCM batch send API uses the same message format and authentication mechanism as the HTTP v1 API. However, it uses a different endpoint. If you want to improve efficiency, you should consider using HTTP/2 to send multiple requests over the same HTTP connection to the HTTP v1 API.

What should we do to use HTTP/2 ? Is there any changes need to be done ? We are using Firebase Admin SDK version 9.2.0

We have migrated the API but we want to confirm whether it is using HTTP/2 .

Answer (score 0):

The advice you are quoting is only relevant for code using the HTTP endpoints directly.  It does not apply to code using the Admin SDK.  The Admin SDK invokes the HTTP endpoints for you, so you don't have to worry about how any of that is implemented.  Also, its behavior can't be changed and should follow the latest protocol specifications.

If you have questions about how the Admin SDK works, you can see all of its source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node).